# Convert 8 digits integer to standard date format in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

For a date column which is like `20190101, 20190102`, how could I change it to `2019/01/01, 2019/01/02` or `2019-01-01, 2019-01-02`? Thanks for your help.

I have tried with `df['date'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using

```
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format='%Y%m%d')
```

Comment: Sorry to bother you, could you review my last question about `price` and `pct-change` please? Thanks.